# Error with my fact table: converting numeric to data type varchar

Tags: sql-server, data-warehouse

I'm doing a datawarehouse and I need to fill my fact table, this is my query but when I run the code returns this error:

> Msg 8115, Level 16, State 5, Line 98
>   Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type varchar.

Does someone know how to solve it?

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image: CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA_01]

[image: CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA_02]

[image: CORSARIO.FACTURA_01]

[image: CORSARIO.FACTURA_02]

[image: CORSARIO.FACTURA_03]

---

```
INSERT INTO dbo.Hechos_Ventas
    SELECT      
        DA.COD_ARTKEY, DT.COD_FECHAKEY,
        DZ.COD_ZONAKEY, DC.COD_IDKEY, FL.FACTURA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_UNITARIO * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_UNITARIO 
        END AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FL.FECHA_FACTURA, 101) AS FECHA_FACT,
        F.TIPO_DOCUMENTO, F.TIPO_CAMBIO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.DESC_TOT_LINEA * - 1 
              ELSE fl.DESC_TOT_LINEA 
        END AS DESCUENTO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.CANTIDAD * - 1 
              ELSE fl.cantidad 
        END AS CANTIDAD,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 * - 1 
              ELSE fl.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 
        END AS IVA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
              ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
        END AS COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END AS PRECIO_TOTAL,
        --GANANCIA
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END - CASE  
                 WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
                    THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
                    ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
              END AS GANANCIA
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Comment: What is the precision of SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA.FECHA_FACTURA? I assume this is a numeric/decimal data type?

Comment: FECHA_FACTURA from FACTURA_LINEA has datetime

Comment: If you change the VARCHAR(10) in your convert to VARCHAR(MAX) do you still receive this error?

Comment: Yes, the same error

Comment: Please include the table schema (all the columns and their types). Additionally, can you narrow it down to what rows are causing the issue? Change the WHERE clause to select subsets of the data until you find exactly one row that causes the issue... knowing the data causing the problem is half the battle to finding a solution.

Comment: Since it's an insert, what is the length of the FECHA_FACTURA column in the Hechos_Ventas table? If you take off the insert do you get the error? It'd really help to just get the schema's of the new table and the old tables.

Comment: FECHA_FACT     VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, I don´t have problem if I execute without the insert into

Comment: I can't answer your question, Gabriella, but I can simplify your query.  If you use `INNER JOIN (select *, case tipo_documento when 'D' then -1 else 1 end as 'multiplier' from SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA) AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA`, you'll be able to use the `multiplier` column in the rest of your select statement, eliminating all the CASEs.

Comment: Please put the table definition in your question, formatted, not in a comment, where it's literally unreadable. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, you can check it now

Comment: Why does your comment say fecha_fact is varchar30 and your code/image say varchar10?

Comment: Gabriela, please put the definition of all tables. I Suspect the problem is the inner join. Do a simple test, remove all fields in the select and try to run the query again.

Comment: @CaiusJard I changed the value, I thought that could be the lenght to  solve the problem

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri I tried the test but it return the same error

Comment: It is perfect; the problem is in the inner. Now you should comment all tables after the auto join with SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA and run the query if the query run, uncomment one more table. Do it until you discover the problem.

Comment: You forgot to put the facto tables structure

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri dbo.Hechos_Ventas (Fact table)

Comment: I need to the tables SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA and SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri after my code/image you can find the SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA (the first 2 images) and SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA (the last 3 images)

Comment: Hi Gabriela, check the data type of hechos_ventas cod_artkey. This field is an integer on the hechos_ventas but in the DIMENSION_ARTICULO  is a varchar(20).  I noticed that some fields are with different precision, is a good practice use the same precision in all fields. Maybe a simple cast resolves this issue.

Comment: @MaurícioPontaltiNeri I repaired the data types but the error persists

Comment: Hi Gabriela, I posted an answer only to show you some code that can help you to identify the problem after you test it I will delete the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to help you in a different way. I created here some SQL Statements, and I need to know each failure in the execution.

If all of them work, we need to create SQL Statements to insert field by field to discover where the problem is. It is not the better technique to identify the problem but if easiest to help you.

First

```
--INSERT INTO dbo.Hechos_Ventas
    SELECT      
        DA.COD_ARTKEY, DT.COD_FECHAKEY,
        DZ.COD_ZONAKEY, DC.COD_IDKEY, FL.FACTURA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_UNITARIO * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_UNITARIO 
        END AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FL.FECHA_FACTURA, 101) AS FECHA_FACT,
        F.TIPO_DOCUMENTO, F.TIPO_CAMBIO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.DESC_TOT_LINEA * - 1 
              ELSE fl.DESC_TOT_LINEA 
        END AS DESCUENTO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.CANTIDAD * - 1 
              ELSE fl.cantidad 
        END AS CANTIDAD,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 * - 1 
              ELSE fl.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 
        END AS IVA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
              ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
        END AS COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END AS PRECIO_TOTAL,
        --GANANCIA
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END - CASE  
                 WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
                    THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
                    ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
              END AS GANANCIA
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Second

```
 SELECT      
    *
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Third

```
 SELECT      
    *
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Fourth

```
SELECT      
*
FROM            
    SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
INNER JOIN 
    SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
--INNER JOIN 
--    DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
--INNER JOIN 
--    DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE        
    (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
    AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Fifth

```
 SELECT      
    *
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    --INNER JOIN 
    --    DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Sixth

```
SELECT      
*
FROM            
    SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
INNER JOIN 
    SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
INNER JOIN 
    DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
WHERE        
    (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
    AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Seventh

```
SELECT      
        --DA.COD_ARTKEY, DT.COD_FECHAKEY,
        --DZ.COD_ZONAKEY, DC.COD_IDKEY, FL.FACTURA,
        --CASE 
        --   WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
        --      THEN FL.PRECIO_UNITARIO * - 1 
        --      ELSE fl.PRECIO_UNITARIO 
        --END AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        --CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FL.FECHA_FACTURA, 101) AS FECHA_FACT,
        --F.TIPO_DOCUMENTO, F.TIPO_CAMBIO,
        --CASE 
        --   WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
        --      THEN FL.DESC_TOT_LINEA * - 1 
        --      ELSE fl.DESC_TOT_LINEA 
        --END AS DESCUENTO,
        --CASE 
        --   WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
        --      THEN FL.CANTIDAD * - 1 
        --      ELSE fl.cantidad 
        --END AS CANTIDAD,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 * - 1 
              ELSE fl.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 
        END AS IVA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
              ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
        END AS COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END AS PRECIO_TOTAL,
        --GANANCIA
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
        END - CASE  
                 WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
                    THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
                    ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
              END AS GANANCIA
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```

Eighth

```
SELECT      
        DA.COD_ARTKEY, DT.COD_FECHAKEY,
        DZ.COD_ZONAKEY, DC.COD_IDKEY, FL.FACTURA,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.PRECIO_UNITARIO * - 1 
              ELSE fl.PRECIO_UNITARIO 
        END AS PRECIO_UNITARIO,
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), FL.FECHA_FACTURA, 101) AS FECHA_FACT,
        F.TIPO_DOCUMENTO, F.TIPO_CAMBIO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.DESC_TOT_LINEA * - 1 
              ELSE fl.DESC_TOT_LINEA 
        END AS DESCUENTO,
        CASE 
           WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
              THEN FL.CANTIDAD * - 1 
              ELSE fl.cantidad 
        END AS CANTIDAD

        --CASE 
     --      WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
     --         THEN FL.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 * - 1 
     --         ELSE fl.TOTAL_IMPUESTO1 
     --   END AS IVA,
     --   CASE 
     --      WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
     --         THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
     --         ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
     --   END AS COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL,
     --   CASE 
     --      WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
     --         THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
     --         ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
     --   END AS PRECIO_TOTAL,
     --   --GANANCIA
     --   CASE 
     --      WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
     --         THEN FL.PRECIO_TOTAL * - 1 
     --         ELSE fl.PRECIO_TOTAL 
     --   END - CASE  
     --            WHEN f.tipo_documento = 'D' 
     --               THEN FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL * -1 
     --               ELSE FL.COSTO_TOTAL_LOCAL 
     --         END AS GANANCIA
    FROM            
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA_LINEA AS FL 
    INNER JOIN 
        SoftlandERP.CORSARIO.FACTURA AS F ON F.FACTURA = FL.FACTURA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ARTICULO DA ON DA.COD_ARTICULO = FL.ARTICULO
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_TIEMPO DT ON DT.FECHA = F.FECHA
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_CLIENTE DC ON DC.ID_CLIENTE = F.CLIENTE
    INNER JOIN 
        DIMENSION_ZONA DZ ON DZ.COD_ZONA = F.ZONA COLLATE DATABASE_DEFAULT
    WHERE        
        (F.ANULADA = 'N') 
        AND (YEAR(FL.FECHA_FACTURA) IN (2015, 2016, 2017))
```